# RegEx URL Match - Everything but

Tags: regex

What should be my regex if I want to block everything (/*) except the folder path (ex: /folder-name)? The folder has other files too that need to be allowed.

Comment: can't you use does *not* match `^...$` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one

```
^/(?!folder-name(/|$)).*$
```

I believe, it matches everything except `/folder-name` dir.